# How to Analyze High memory usage of Node service memory dump?

Tags: node.js, windbg, memory-dump

According to https://azureossd.github.io/2015/09/18/taking-a-crash-dump-of-nodejava-process-using-the-procdump-on-azure-webapp/

we could collect the memory dump of node.exe with ProcDump, where we can use WinDBG to open it.

Are there any tools or maybe WinDBG extensions including its commands that could help us investigate high memory?

Comment: A dump is a standard format simply load it on windbg and inspect------------------- windbg -c "!analyze -v" -z foo.dmp   will print a stacktrace and exception details.====== for a preliminary understanding deep diving needs some expertise

Comment: As a quick and dirty first parse given you have a dump file, you could just try using strings64 from Sysinternals to find all strings in the dmp file and pipe the output to a file.  More often that not, it can be revealing.  Otherwise, you might be better off using Windows Performance Recorder and maybe create a Heap usage trace if you can reproduce it?

Comment: @blabb If you set a high memory condition in ProcDump, there will just be a breakpoint in the crash dump, IMHO, and `!analyze` is quite useless. I don't know what memory of a node.js application looks like. I guess `!address -summary` will not be very helpful since it either results in native heaps or VirtualAlloc.

Comment: What about [heapdump](https://www.npmjs.com/package/heapdump) for looking at the memory and [siege](https://www.joedog.org/siege-home/) to reproduce the leak? Use dedicated JS tools. I've not come across Node.JS plugins for WinDbg.